# ExpandableListView child's radio button

Tags: expandablelistview, android, expandablelistadapter

I have an Expandable listview where each item (group) has multiple children, and each child has a radio button. In each group, only one radio button can be selected.

In my attempts, I am able to make only one radio button active, however not in each group, but in the whole list. Also when a group is expanded the the position of the radio button selected is changed.

Here my code for the `setOnChildClickListener`

```
ExpListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        Log.v("TESTING","On Child Click");
        if (groupPosition == 0) {
            Log.v("TESTING","OnChildClick - groupPosition = 0");
            RadioButton last = checkedRadio1;
            RadioButton r = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_button);

            if (last != null)
                last.setChecked(false);
            r.setChecked(true);
            checkedRadio1 = r;

            return true;
        }
        else if (groupPosition == 1) {
            RadioButton last = checkedRadio2;
            RadioButton r = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_button);

            if (last != null)
                last.setChecked(false);
            r.setChecked(true);
            checkedRadio2 = r;

            return true;
        }
        else if(groupPosition == 2) {
            RadioButton last = checkedRadio3;
            RadioButton r = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_button);

            if (last != null)
                last.setChecked(false);
            r.setChecked(true);
            checkedRadio3 = r;

            return true;
        }

        else return false;
    }
});
```

And here's the code for the `setOnItemLongClickListener` (I want it on the long click)

```
ExpListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
       if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(l) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
          int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(l);

            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                    && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                ExpListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            ExpListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;

            return true;
        }

        else return false;
    }
});
```

How can make sure that the position of the child is the right one? For instance if I check second child in the first group, then expand the second group (the first group automatically collapses) I have the first child in the second group checked. How can I solve this? And how can I make the 'single select' mode only between children of the same group?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you might have to maintain a hashmap of a group of objects that contains the position of the group and also the position of the child selected. And use this hashmap to set the selections in the adapter.

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille can you please elaborate on that point?